# asp.net inline tags within a table cell

Tags: asp.net, syntax, styles, inline

I cannot get the "style width" value to display correctly when using inline syntax. It renders as:

style=""

Any suggestions.

```
<table>
    <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
        <td style="width: <%= this.LabelColumnWidth %>">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What are you pulling the width from? is it from another asp.net control or from code behind?

Comment: @Robert please show us the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer suggested by Eric is almost correct. Only, it should have a = instead of #

```
<td style='<%= "width:" + this.LabelColumnWidth %>' >
```

A hash is used only when you need to include a eval() or bind() function. Otherwise, use the = sign.

Answer (score 1):

give this a whirl

```
<td style="width: <%# this.LabelColumnWidth %>">
```

**EDIT: (now that I know a little more)**

why dont you add an `id` to that `td` something like this

```
 <td id="test" runat="server">
```

and then in code behind do

```
 test.style = "width: 100px;" // or whatever
```

Comment: No, I normally use the `<%#` instead of the `<%=`.. although I'm not sure the difference.

Comment: Thank, I am trying to avoid converting those to server controls. But that may be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

inline Attempt 2:

give this a whirl

```
<td style='<%# "width: " + this.LabelColumnWidth %>'>
```

Thinking maybe the whole thing needs to be in the inline code. and not just the value of width.